# Change TabNine's priority in suggestion window

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellisense

I have been using TabNine in VSCode for quite some time. It has been great except for when I have to choose function/other names rather than TabNine's suggestions.

My question is, Can we change any setting such that all the TabNine's suggestions appear after Intellisense's suggestions?
[image]

As seen above, the tabnine(color) suggestion is at the top, taking the most priority.
I want it to be at the bottom or even change the priority.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is, Can we change any setting such that all the TabNine's
> suggestions appear after Intellisense's suggestions?

Yes but not with the official extension, the official Tabnine extension for vscode does not support this feature so far.

There is however [a fork of the vscode plugin which adds this option](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=svipas.code-autocomplete&ssr=false#review-details) (I use it myself and find it quite useful)

Comment: I'm trying to find the setting to change the order of suggestions, where is it?

Answer (score 1):

One of Tabnine's developers here. Thank you for using Tabnine and spreading the word about it.

Unfortunately, Tabnine does not support suggestions prioritization. We are constantly improving the suggestions to make them worth the top places in your suggestion window.

We will take your request into account and prioritize it.

Thanks!

Comment: IntelliSense's default completion options are 100% accurate and also tell us the type of the value (function or variable or interface). Sometimes, we do not want to code complete but just want to know what variables/methods are available by adding a dot. Tabnine is currently working as both a snippet generator and provider of default intellisense code completion. I think user should have the option to configure how they want to use it.

Comment: @sziraqui thank you for the feedback, we will look into that. Thanks!

Comment: This is a problem in Visual Studio (not code) as well and turns me off the tabnine product completely. tabnine is not able to do proper intelligence and just offers me garbage GPT-2 style completes for method names that do not even exist.