# How to change Intellisense priority of plugins in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellisense

I installed a plugin (tabnine) that gives Intellisense (Conde hint). I like it as it gives hints in places where the language plugin doesn't.
More often then not these hints are useful. But in situation where the language plugin does gives hits they happen to be more accurate/useful then hints given by tabnine. But tabnine's hints appear on the top.

Is there any way to change this. I would like the tabnine's hints to appear in the bottom of the list.

Comment: I have this same question. Please mention what you have tried. If I find something I will post an answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change TabNine's priority in suggestion window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66197633/change-tabnines-priority-in-suggestion-window)